# How to create a simple function which prints a number list up to an input integer value

Tags: python, list, range

Given an input number n, what would be the simplest function to output a list up to this value.

```
n = int(raw_input("Enter a number:"))
x = [1:n+1]
def work(n):
    print range(x)
```

Comment: You can do it using `range` i guess. [Doc link](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#range)

Comment: This is invalid python syntax

Comment: `list = [1,2,3,4,5]` , print list[1:3]

Comment: @Akshay output [2,3]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use [`range`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#range),

```
n = int(raw_input("Enter a number:"))

def work(n):
    print(range(1, n+1))

work(n)
```

Comment: @sparkandshine did you test this, it doesn't work for me

Comment: @AmyRose, yes, I do. It works for me. Which Python version do u use?

Comment: @AmyRose, you should call the function `work(n)` as my updated answer.

Comment: thanks for your help, is there a simpler way to achieve this?

Comment: How much simpler do you wanna get...?

Comment: @AmyRose, just use `range(1, n+1)`.